# The Hausdorff dimension for sum of sets

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

> Assume $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that  $\dim_H(A+B)\le
>  \dim_HA+\dim_HB $?

When $\dim_HA+\dim_HB\ge n$, this is trivial.

The line $10$ in the link [1](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Ealuffi/archive/paper494.pdf) says that the answer for lower-box dimension is positive. But What about Hausdorff dimension?

Comment: Can you prove it for $n=1$?

Comment: I would take $A, B$ to be Cantor sets.

Comment: @JCAA No. Even for $\mathbb{R}$ it is difficult. Of course if $B$ is countable, then $\dim_H(A+B)=\dim_H \cup_{b\in B} (A+b)=\sup _{b\in B}\dim_H (A+b)=\dim_H A\le \dim_H A+\dim_HB$.

Comment: I suggested Cantor sets. These can have very different Hausdorff dimensions.

Comment: @JCAA When $A,B$ are Cantor, then $d_H(A)+d_HB)>1$

Comment: That is true for the "middle third" set. There are many different Cantor sets.

Comment: Yes. but for them, How can I calculate $\dim(A+B)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 7.8 page 97 of Falconer's book *Fractal geometry* gives an example of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of Hausdorff dimension 0 and whose sum is of Hausdorff dimension 1.